# return address of dlsym and Address of Function Pointer assigned

Tags: c++, c++11, dll, function-pointers, dlsym

```
void* l = dlsym(lib,"_ZN11Environment9LibLogger14log_processingEiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjS6_z");
*(void **)&log_fcn   = l;
std::cout<<"Address"<<<<l<<"LOG_FCN "<<log_fcn<<std::endl;
```

I am trying to print address of `l` and `log_fcn` but both are not same. Why is that, and how can I get address of `dlsym` assign to function pointer?

Output example:

```
l= 0x7efe10eabaa0 LOG_FCN 1
```

void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string frmt, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...); function decleration

Comment: @KonradRudolph void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string frmt, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...);

Comment: `(void*)log_fcn`? the stream seems to convert it to bool instead of pointer otherwise

Comment: The compiler tries to convert log_fcn to something that can be printed, and because function pointers are not convertible to void*, the only valid match is `bool`

Comment: You should convert `l` to `decltype(log_fcn)`, not assign to `log_fcn` through a `void*` lvalue. The latter is an aliasing violation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an `operator <<` for `void*`, but not for function pointers.
Function pointers are implicitly converted to `bool`, not `void*`, and `bool` prints as `0` or `1` by default.

Your `1` output indicates that `log_fcn` is not the null pointer.

Convert it when printing:

```
std::cout << "Address" << l << "LOG_FCN "<< reinterpret_cast<void*>(log_fcn) << std::endl;
```

I would recommend that you also do the assignment in the conventional form, by casting the right-hand side:

```
log_fcn = reinterpret_cast<decltype(log_fcn)>(l);
```

Comment: The unnatural casting on the left side comes from the `dlsym` manual page. It states it’s the workaround for that in C99, casting `void*` to a function pointer is undefined.

Comment: This is C++, not C99.

Comment: Well, yes. In C++ rules are stricter. Don’t remember if there is *any* standard-conforming way in C++.

Comment: @numzero `reinterpret_cast<decltype(log_fcn)>(l)` and `decltype(log_fcn)(l)` are standard-conforming in C++, although conditionally-supported.