# error: invalid cast from type ‘void (*)(int)’ {aka ‘void (*)(int)’} to type ‘void’

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, function-pointers

```
void* l = dlsym(lib,"_ZN11Environment9LibLogger14log_processingEiNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEEjS6_z"); 

void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...) = reinterpret_cast<void (*log_fcn)>(l);
```

above log_fcn is a function pointer i am casting it but facing error

Comment: `void (*log_fcn)` is not the type you want to cast to.  You want `void (*)(int, std::string, unsigned int, std::string, ...)`.  I would suggest using an alias.

Comment: extern void (*log_fcn)(int level,std::string, unsigned int, std::string, ...); is function pointer deceleration in its .h file

Comment: @MilesBudnek can you please suggest to use alias and get it.

Comment: `using LogFunction = void(*)(int, std::string, unsigned int, std::string, ...); LogFunction log_fcn = retinterpret_cast<LogFunction>(l);`

Comment: @MilesBudnek copied and used same getting linker error.

Comment: _Some linker error_ cannot be solved via type-cast.

Comment: This seems like a new profile for [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17182382/m-n-adarsh-kumar). The question is a follow up  question of [warning: inline variables are only available with ‘-std=c++17’ or ‘-std=gnu++17’ how to suppress it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72181312/warning-inline-variables-are-only-available-with-std-c17-or-std-gnu17/72182461#72182461).

Comment: @anooprana yes it's my personal account I wanted to know why conversion is not happening so out of interest posted it.

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond what would be desireable solution for this.

Comment: You should quote the linker error message you got; it might be completely unrelated to the type-cast

Comment: @LorinczyZsigmond getting as below. /usr/include/c++/9/ostream:622:more undefined references to log_fcn [abi:cxx11] follow

Comment: Some object module [the one that contains the definition of functor-variable `log_fcn`] is missing from linkage list.

Comment: `log_fcn` is a variable, not a type. Why don't you use the answer you accepted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72184187/return-address-of-dlsym-and-address-of-function-pointer-assigned)?

Comment: @molbdnilo in previous question I just wanted to print the value of log_fcn to check the address what it holds. How I can I use here?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want

```
void (*log_fcn)(int level, std::string format, unsigned int line_no, std::string file_name, ...) = 
   reinterpret_cast<decltype(log_fcn)>(l);
```

Comment: here decltype means function pointer type right .... = reinterpret_cast<void(log_fcn)>(l);